# Getting the Value of a CheckBoxPreference

Tags: android, checkboxpreference

I want to get the value from a `CheckBoxPreference`, I have defined it in `Convert/res/xml/settings.xml`, here is how it looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <CheckBoxPreference 
        android:key="allow_internet"
        android:title="@string/internet_label"
        android:summaryOn="@string/internet_on"
        android:summaryOff="@string/internet_off"
        android:defaultValue="true" />
    <CheckBoxPreference 
        android:key="decimal_output"
        android:title="@string/decimal_title"
        android:summaryOn="@string/decimal_summary_on"
        android:summaryOff="@string/decimal_summary_off" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

My question is how do I get the value of the `CheckBoxPreference` in my `MainActivity.java` file, because there is no `android:id` attribute for `CheckBoxPreference`, there is also a `Settings.java` file in my `Convert/scr/.../Settings.java`, it looks like:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }
}
```

Comment: i would advice you to use the SharedPreferences though ... very flexible ... if you want I can post the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CheckboxPreferences are stored in SharedPreferences. In your MainActivity, you can use:

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.settings, false);
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
boolean allowInternet = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("allow_internet", true);
```

Comment: Hi TIna, this helped me out a lot, but when I use the `getBoolean("allow_internet",true)` is always returns true. I need it to return either true or false.

Answer (score 0):

I also get only TRUE when in `settings.xml`use
`defaultValue=false`.

I resolved use `bool.xml`.
But it's good practice use https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings  instead PreferenceManager